# Imagen oficial docker laravel 7 me da error de memoria. Imagen: bitnami/laravel:7.30.1

Tags: laravel, docker, memoria

estaba probando la imagen oficial de deocker para laravel 7 de bitnami `bitnami/laravel:7.30.1` . Le **vinculo el volumen donde esta la app sin problemas** y en el docker lo vinculo a `/app` que es donde, en teoria, esta.

Y viendo los logs de ejecucion del contenedor dice lo siguiente :

```
2023-07-23 12:59:24 Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
2023-07-23 12:59:24 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
2023-07-23 12:59:51 PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) in phar:///opt/bitnami/php/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90
2023-07-23 12:58:47 
2023-07-23 12:58:47 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) in phar:///opt/bitnami/php/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90
2023-07-23 12:58:47 
2023-07-23 12:58:47 Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.2023-07-23T10:59:51.184770876Z 
2023-07-23 12:59:51 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) in phar:///opt/bitnami/php/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90
2023-07-23 12:59:51 
2023-07-23T10:59:51.293005482Z Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

Estoy en **windows 10** . Se que funciona peor docker aqui pero no creo que tenga nada que ver.

Parece como que necesita mas memoria, pero la app de laravel que le he montado esta vacia practicamente, no deberia de tener ningun problema de memoria por la complejidad que pudiera tener.

Este es el volumen que he montado :

[image: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\prueba : docker\test_laravel]